# CAML Query for Complex AND or OR scenarios

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, caml-query

I want to create CAML Query for following scenario,

`(Metadata Name ="Author1" AND Value="Nitin Jagtap") AND (Metadata Name ="Program" AND Value="MBA")`.

I have tried but not able to create CAML query for same. I have used CAML Designer for same but unable to get proper result.

```
     Following is the CAML Query which is generated by using CAML Designer but it is not giving results        
  <Where>
  <And>
     <And>
        <And>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='Metadata_x0020_Name' />
              <Value Type='Lookup'>Author 1</Value>
           </Eq>
           <Eq>
              <FieldRef Name='Value' />
              <Value Type='Text'>Nitin Jagtap</Value>
           </Eq>
        </And>
        <Eq>
           <FieldRef Name='Metadata_x0020_Name' />
           <Value Type='Lookup'>Program</Value>
        </Eq>
     </And>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Value' />
        <Value Type='Text'>MBA</Value>
     </Eq>
  </And>
```

I have a list having name “Metadata Values” which contains two columns

- Metadata Name (which is a Lookup Column from Metadata List)
- Value (which is Single line of text column)
  The list “Metadata Values” contains multiple records for each Metadata Name having different- different values or same values.

How should I create proper CAML query, so it will gives proper results. Please guide me.

Comment: Is that really a valid scenario? You can not have f.e. `Value` equal both `MBA` and `Nitin Jagtap`. Should there be an `OR`  between the parentesis instead?

Comment: And the structure looks wrong too, I'd go back to CAML Designer and try configuring this again

Comment: Thanks Robert,for your reply.This is a valid scenario.Okay I will try using OR

Answer (score 0):

Your query for Managed metadata(Multivalues) Column should be:

```
<FieldRef Name='Metadata_x0020_Name' />
  <values>
      <Value Type='Lookup'>Author 1</Value>
      <Value Type='Lookup'>Program</Value>
  </values>
```